# Coded flowchart and unable to return OutArgument

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I am create flow chart workflow using code (instead of design time)

**Code**

```
static Flowchart CreateFlowChart()
{
    Variable<string> response = new Variable<string>();
    Variable<string> isApproved = new Variable<string>();

    FlowStep approved = new FlowStep
    {
        Action = new Assign
        {
            To = new OutArgument<string> (isApproved),
            Value = new InArgument<string>((context) => response.Get(context))
        }
    };

    FlowStep rejected = new FlowStep
    {
        Action = new Assign
        {
            DisplayName = "Approved",
            To = new OutArgument<string>(isApproved),
            Value = new InArgument<string>((context) => response.Get(context))
        }
    };

    FlowDecision flowDecision = new FlowDecision
    {

        Condition = ExpressionServices.Convert<bool>((ctx) => response.Get(ctx).ToString() == "approved"),
        True = approved,
        False = rejected
    };

    FlowStep LineManagerApproval = new FlowStep
    {
        Action = new ReadLine 
        {
            BookmarkName = readLineBookmark,
            Result = new OutArgument<string>(response)
        },

        Next = flowDecision
    };           

    Flowchart flowChart = new Flowchart
    {
        DisplayName = "Line Manager Approval Process",
        Variables = { response, isApproved },
        StartNode = LineManagerApproval,
        Nodes = 
        {
            LineManagerApproval,
            flowDecision,
            approved,
            rejected
        }
    };
    return flowChart;
}
```

I am setting `OutArgument<string>` in my activity post to flow decision.

When workflow completes i am expecting to have `e.OutPuts["isApproved"]` but `e.OutPuts` always give count 0;

```
application.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Workflow {0} Completed.", e.InstanceId);
    //bool isApproved = (bool)e.Outputs["isApproved"];

};
```

Basically i am struggling to return OutArgument from flow chart.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

IsApproved should be set as an outArgument at the workflow level.  You seem to have it set as a Variable.

Comment: Yes it was defined as Variable but later it is used as an OutArgument e.g.  To = new OutArgument<string> (isApproved), So not sure what you mean here?

Comment: Yes, but that is as the OutArgument of a Flowstep so it has scope in that Flowstep.  You require an outArgument that has FlowChart scope.  Check out Maurice's answer to a similar problem here:. http://techqa.info/programming/question/6272553/programmatically-creating-an-assign-in-a-flowchart-workflow